# Как вывести строки в DF по списку значений в столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, обработка-данных

У меня есть вот такой DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['100','110','120','130','140','150','160','170'], 
'B': ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','y'], 'C': ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','y']})

A   B   C
0   100 a   a
1   110 b   b
2   120 c   c
3   130 d   d
4   140 f   f
5   150 g   g
6   160 h   h
7   170 y   y
```

И есть список значений, который я получил из другой таблицы, допустим:

```
list = [110,140,170]
```

Как мне, применив эти значения к столбцу А, вывести по ним соответствующие строки?

Должно получиться вот так:

```
    A   B   C
1   110 b   b
2   140 f   f
3   170 y   y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения в списке и в столбце должны быть одинакового типа, а у вас в столбце `A` - строки, а в списке - целые числа.

```
In [138]: s = pd.Series(list_).astype(str)

In [139]: df.query("A in @s")
Out[139]: 
     A  B  C
1  110  b  b
4  140  f  f
7  170  y  y
```

либо наоборот - приводим столбец к числовому типу данных и после этого ищем:

```
In [141]: df[df["A"].astype(int).isin(list_)]
Out[141]: 
     A  B  C
1  110  b  b
4  140  f  f
7  170  y  y
```

Если же в ваших реальных данных типы данных в столбце и списке совпадают, то решение будет выглядеть проще:

```
res = df.query("A in @list_")
```

или так:

```
res = df[df["A"].isin(list_)]
```

PS не используйте зарезервированные слова (такие как `list`) в качестве имен собственных переменных, функций и классов, чтобы избежать ненужных проблем.

Comment: Да, на самом деле мой список, это столбец с тем же именем из другой таблицы, т.е. серия. И он тут ни к чему. Т.е. решение, как вы написали, очень простое:
res = df.query("A in @list_")

Большое спасибо!